# plugin enqueue style on all pages

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, wp-enqueue-style

I need to enqueue a style sheet in my plugin to work on the front end of Wordpress.  Here is what I have.  Will someone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
function add_my_stylesheet1()  {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'myStyles', plugins_url( 'css/styles.css', __FILE__ ) );

}

add_action('admin_print_styles', 'add_my_stylesheet1');
```

Comment: you're enquing it on the wrong hook

Answer (score 1):

You're enquing on the **admin**_enqueue_scripts hook, which is why it's only showing up on admin pages

If we look at an example from the official documentation:

```
/**
 * Proper way to enqueue scripts and styles
 */
function wpdocs_theme_name_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'style-name', get_stylesheet_uri() );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'script-name', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/example.js', array(), '1.0.0', true );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpdocs_theme_name_scripts' );
```

we see the `wp_enqueue_scripts` hook being used instead. Use that hook instead of `admin_print_styles` to print on the frontend

Comment: So are you saying to add it like this? It does not work.
function wpdocs_theme_name_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'style-name', get_stylesheet_uri() );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'script-name', get_template_directory_uri() . 'css/styles.css', array(), '1.0.0', true );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpdocs_theme_name_scripts' );

Comment: That function isn't a copy-paste fix, it's the example out of the official docs to demonstrate normal enquing. You need to use the `wp_enqueue_scripts` action, not the `admin_print_styles` action to show on the frontend

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `admin_enqueue_scripts` hook. So your function would be like this...

```
function add_my_stylesheet1() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'myStyles', plugins_url( __FILE__ ) . ' css/styles.css' );
}
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'add_my_stylesheet1' );
```

Comment: I tried that hook earlier and then again since you suggested it, but I still can't get it to work.

Comment: I just edited my answer to change how `wp_enqueue_style()` is called.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, Here is my final solution:

```
function my_test() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'shortcode', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'css/shortcodes.css' );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_test' );
```